# How to make a CardView Resizable automatically when a textView is populated with data or Information

Tags: java, android

Am trying to populate a TextView under a CardView , but the information is not complete. How can I make the CardView to resize automatically , to any kind of information populating a TextView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    card_view:contentPaddingTop="20dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPaddingLeft="50dp"
    card_view:contentPaddingRight="50dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SYNOPSIS"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"

            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#300145"


            />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/synopsis_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="SYNOPSIS TWO"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what is wrong with making `layout_height` and `layout_width` of the cardview as `wrap_content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the card view xml file replace :

```
android:layout_height="match_parent" with android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And in text view @+id/synopsis_txt :

```
android:layout_height="30dp" with android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```